# Matplotib Finance (mplfinance) formatting axes of chart unsing mpf.plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplfinance

The MPL finance is great, however I cant seem to tweak the formatting of the axes.  In the image I would like to show only the date, without the 00:00 time. Also the price, I would like to add a $ currency and decimal places (variable).

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf

df = pd.read_csv(csv)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
cols = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
df = df[cols]
df = df.sort_values(by=['date'], ascending=False)
df = df.set_index('date')
```

And then calling mplfinance with (inserting style):

```
mpf.plot(df, type='candle', volume=True style= *style*)
```

Generates the below charts, I have highlight the parts I would like to change if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the date format, you can add kwarg `datetime_format`, for example:

```py
mpf.plot(df, type='candle', volume=True, style=s, datetime_format='%b %d')
```

For the y-axis tick labels, I would suggest that you simply adjust the y-axis label (not the tick labels) using kwarg `ylabel='Price ($)'` or something like that.

---

Alternatively if you really want a $ sign next to each tick label, you can do this:

- [first gain access to the mplfinance axes objects](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/wiki/Acessing-mplfinance-Figure-and-Axes-objects).
- Then set the formatter for that axes, as follows:

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter

fig, axlist = mpf.plot(df,type='candle',volume=True,style=s,
                       datetime_format='%b %d',returnfig=True)

axlist[0].yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('$%.2f'))

mpf.show()
```

### Result with Default Style

[image]

Comment: I'm not in finance, so I only use this package when looking at questions on SO, but I can see that it's a nice piece of engineering. Again, thanks for your effort. See you around.

Comment: It answer is a explains a lot about how to use the axes method with mpl finance. Thank you friend, saved my time and confusion.